# erro ao inserir dados em tabela postgres com sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Sou meio iniciante nos estudos em Sequelize e estou passando por um bugzinho. Estou tentando desenvolver uma API para treinar meu conhecimento e na minha primeira tentativa de executar o método post de Usuário me loga o seguinte erro:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
at C.run (/home/joaomarcelo/akuma_api/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:1:1272)
at /home/joaomarcelo/akuma_api/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/sequelize.js:1:7125
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async v.insert (/home/joaomarcelo/akuma_api/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:1:6936)
at async User.save (/home/joaomarcelo/akuma_api/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/model.js:1:53725)
at async Function.create (/home/joaomarcelo/akuma_api/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/model.js:1:30305)
at async store (/home/joaomarcelo/akuma_api/src/controllers/UserController.js:7:22)

Se alguém puder me ajudar, serei grato.

Seguem os códigos:
/migrations: `

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   await queryInterface.createTable('users', { 
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name:{
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    tripulation:{
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    created_At: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    updated_At:{
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
 },

down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
 }
};
```

`

/model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class User extends Model {
static init(connection){
    super.init({
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        tripulation: DataTypes.STRING
    }, { sequelize: connection })
}
}

module.exports = User;
```

/database/index.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database');

const User = require('../models/User');

const connect = new Sequelize(dbConfig);

User.init(connect)

module.exports = connect;
```

/controllers:

```
 const User = require('../models/User');

 module.exports = {
   async store(req,res){
    const { name, tripulation } = req.body;

    const user = await User.create({ name, tripulation })

    res.json(user);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

a todos que lerem a pergunta e se propuserem a responder, meu agradecimento.
Já consegui resolver o bug: no migration de user as chaves created_at e updated_at estavam com o "at" maiúsculo ('At').